# Create a dataframe using while loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, while-loop

i want to create a new dataframe using while loop.

The input is:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,3],'b':[10,20]})
```

I want to work on one row so i have selected that row:

```
s=a.loc[a['c']==3]
```

Now i want to create a new dataframe `e` using values in `s` with while loop
I want to apply condition that if `s['c']<s['b']` add `2`
And return `s['b']` if the value `>=s['b']`
The required output should look like this:

```
e=pd.DataFrame([3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,20])
#(i am not allowed to add picture thats why)
```

I have tried these codes:

```
e=pd.DataFrame(s['c'])
for i in e:
    while e[i,0]<s['b']:
        e[i,0]=e[i,0]+2
    i=i+1
```

2nd try:

```
e=pd.DataFrame(s['c'])
for i in e:
    while e[i,0]<s['b']:
        e.iat[i,0]=e.iat[i,0]+2
        i=i+1
```

Comment: Why not use data frame append after using a dictionary to define an empty schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas dataframes are normally used for manipulating existing data through unified operations on full columns/rows, not iterating over things, but you can accomplish the effect you're looking for by just generating the list normally and passing it into dataframe:

```
i = s['c'][1]
l = []
while True:
    l.append(i)
    i += 2
    if i >= s['b'][1]:
        l.append(s['b'][1])
        break

e=pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Comment: Ok got it .Thank u so much for the help